# Assign Owner based on selected category

Tags: apex

I'm new in apex trigger.
I want to assign owner **(standard lookup field)** in incident **(custom object)** based on selected category **(lookup field)** using apex trigger. 
API Name for object incident is `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c` , category lookup field is `BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c` but i don't know API Name for owner field because it only have field name and field label. Can anyone help me to create this trigger?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why do you explicitly want to accomplish this using a trigger? Have you looked into how workflows can also handle this type of requirement?

Comment: Yes i know that workflow can handle this but workflow has limit until 500 workflow, if i want assign 100 categories using workflow it wouldn't handle other requirement i need

Answer (score 2):

The Owner API name is usually OwnerId.

If you use Eclipse with the Salesforce plugin, there is a handy way of seeing the API names by clicking on the "salesforce.schema" file in your project. This lists all the objects and their field API names.

Comment: I use BMC RemedyForce platform in salesforce, how can i seeing the API names?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that platform, but there are object references docs such as [this one for Contact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger on your custom object like :

```
    trigger triggername on Incident__c(before insert, before update){

    Group g = [select Id from Group where Name = 'YOURGROUPNAME' and Type = 'Queue'];
    String cat = 'Account Administration','Category A','Category B';

    for(Incident__c obj : trigger.new){
        if(cat.contains(FKCategory__c))
            obj.OwnerId = g.Id;
    }
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i can't use this code. It has error like this: Variable does not exist: BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c.

BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c and owner are lookup field
May you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you are using some package named "BMCServiceDesk". Try to remove "BMCServiceDesk__" this text before object name as well as field name.

Comment: I using this trigger to assign owner based on selected category:


But i can't using it
Do you know the matter?

Comment: trigger AssignOwner on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(before insert){
    Set<String> Categories= new Set<String>{'Account Administration','Category A','Category B'};
    for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c obj : trigger.new){
      List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> l_cp = [SELECT Id, BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c=:Categories];
            for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c am_cp : l_cp) {
                obj.Owner = l_cp.get(obj.Owner).OwnerId;
              
  
              update l_cp ;
       
     }

    
       
    }
}

Comment: Ok so if FKCategory__c is among those three values which you have mentioned then in this case which owner you want to assign in owner field?

Comment: If i select category "Account Adminstration", i want assign to user or queue for example to queue payroll

Comment: In that case you have to query the queue and then assign its is in owner accordingly. Try following code:
Also, please make sure that the queue is available to the custom object "Incident__c".

trigger triggername on Incident__c(before insert, before update){

 Group g = [select Id from Group where Name = 'YOURGROUPNAME' and Type = 'Queue'];
 String cat = 'Account Administration','Category A','Category B';
 
    for(Incident__c obj : trigger.new){
        if(cat.contains(FKCategory__c))
            obj.OwnerId = g.Id;
    }
}

I have also edited the code in my answer above, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code above, but it can't work.
I try this code: 
Can you let me know which part i've missed?

trigger AssignOwner on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(before insert){
   Set Categories= new Set{'Account Administration','Category A','Category B'};

```
Group g = [select Id from Group where Name = 'Payroll' and Type = 'Queue'];

for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c obj : trigger.new){
  List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> l_cp = [SELECT Id, BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c=:Categories];

for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c c: l_cp ) {
     if(Categories.contains(l_cp))
        obj.OwnerId = g.Id;      
     }
 }
```

}